# Passing a condition as a Proc/Lambda/Block in recursive function causes it to exit once the condition inside the lambda has evaluated to true. Why?

Tags: ruby, recursion, lambda, block, proc

So I want to create a recursive function that, when given an array, will return an array of elements that meet the condition passed into the function. I have tried using lambdas, blocks and procs, and every time they exit the function once that condition evaluates to true, rather than when the base case is met. I want to know why this is and how I can overcome it.

```
def find_by_condition_recur(arr, count, acc, &block)
  return acc if count == arr.count - 1
  puts count
  puts arr.count
  if block.call(arr[count])
    acc << arr[count]
  else
    find_by_condition_recur(arr, count += 1, acc, &block)
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

```
def find_by_condition_recur(arr, findBy, count, acc)
  return acc if count == arr.count - 1
  puts count
  puts arr.count
  if findBy.call(arr[count])
    acc << arr[count]
    find_by_condition_recur(arr, findBy, count += 1, acc)
  end
end

search_condition = Proc.new { |x| x % 3 == 0 }
```

Comment: My Ruby is quite weak but since I know it's a common problem when writing recursive algorithms - don't you need to `return acc << arr[count]` and `find_by_condition_recur(arr, count += 1, acc, &block)`? If Ruby doesn't automatically return the result of the last expression in the function, then you're not returning the result of the recursive call, so it's lost.

Comment: AFAIK it does use last expression as return value

Comment: you're only recursing if `block.call(..)` is false; if it's `true` you're adding the result to `acc` and never telling it to go to the next element

Comment: Does the block has a return statement?

Comment: You need to be careful which one you use.  A lambda will return normally, like a regular method, but a proc will try to return from the current context.

Comment: @SimpleLime You were right but now it is returning, nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some working code for you:

```
def find_by_condition_recur(arr, idx=0, acc=[], &findBy)
  return acc if idx == arr.count
  if findBy.call(arr[idx])
    acc << arr[idx]
  end
  find_by_condition_recur(arr, idx + 1, acc, &findBy)
end

find_by_condition_recur([1,2,3]) { |num| num != 2 }
# => [1,3]
```

There were two major fixes:

1. The base case is `idx == arr.count`, not `idx == arr.count - 1`. You only want to return here if the idx is out-of-bounds - `arr.count - 1` is *in bounds*, so if you return in that case, you would skip the last iteration.
2. You need to move the final `find_by_condition_recur` call to outside of the `if findBy.call` block, otherwise recursion will stop as soon as the condition fails (and the rest of the array won't be processed).

Other than that there were a few refactorings I made:

1. Default values for arguments. There's no reason to have to specify `idx` or `acc` arguments the first time the method is called - we know are they are going to be `0` and `[]` respectively so let's just set those as the default values.
2. Block should always be the last argument, otherwise you are forcing the caller to use an ugly proc/lambda literal. It's much more idiomatic to use blocks, and you can only use blocks when it's the last argument.
3. Using `idx` instead of `count` as the variable name, this is just more accurate.

Comment: You're an angel. Thank you!